# Custom alert for unexpected sources - Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I wish to set-up a custom alert that highlights unexpected sources, for example a formerly unknown site linking to mine.

This can be done setting the "compare to past" check-box and then login at the list for a +100% change AND the previous visits are equal to 0

I'd like to automate this, but I can't find the right options when building a custom alerts.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [InboundLinkAlerts](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com) by embeddedanalytics.  The service was built precisely to detect new linking sites.

(disclaimer: I work with the company).